# Finding contiguous blocks in a 2D array

Tags: arrays, search, 2d

Say you had an array in the form:

```
[ 
  [2, 2, 3, 4],
  [2, 3, 5, 5],
  [2, 2, 2, 5],
  [3, 2, 2, 4],
]
```

and wanted to find coordinates of numerically contiguous blocks, in this case:

```
[
  # the 2s:
  [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), (3,2)],
  # and the 5s:
  [(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)]
]
```

how would you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm on each cell. (Note: flag already processed cells also during fills to not take them into account multiple times)